# How to Debug a flow built in process builder

Tags: workflow, process-builder, debugging

I have a workflow that generates a task. Based n creating a custom object

I have been looking in the logs to make sure it's working. But, now I'm stumped. Does anyone know how to understand this?

23:18:39.26 (52354852)|WF_SPOOL_ACTION_BEGIN|Workflow
23:18:39.26 (52408728)|WF_ACTION| Flow Trigger: 1;
23:18:39.26 (52426167)|WF_RULE_EVAL_END
23:18:39.26 (53167647)|WF_FLOW_ACTION_BEGIN|09L6F000000TPxm
23:18:39.54 (54700215)|FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|00D90000000zLUc|3006F000000HGQX|3016F0000000YRY
23:18:39.54 (56652182)|FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_END|6080efeb17ccf84240e2573571cd15447f30734-4ad9|Attitude to activity
23:18:39.57 (57141012)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEWS_BEGIN|1
23:18:39.57 (57885847)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|6080efeb17ccf84240e2573571cd15447f30734-4ad9|Attitude to activity
23:18:39.57 (75536714)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_END|6080efeb17ccf84240e2573571cd15447f30734-4ad9|Attitude to activity
23:18:39.57 (100612709)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEWS_END|1
23:18:39.26 (100708389)|WF_FLOW_ACTION_ERROR|09L6F000000TPxm|3006F000000HGQX|Error executing flow: Attitude_to_activity, FlowDefId: 3006F000000HGQX, FlowVersionId: 3016F0000000YRY
23:18:39.26 (100734715)|WF_FLOW_ACTION_ERROR_DETAIL|**An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow**
An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the flow.  Please contact your system administrator for more information.
23:18:39.26 (101080774)|WF_FLOW_ACTION_END|09L6F000000TPxm
23:18:39.26 (101100943)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Workflow:01I90000002ALag
23:18:39.26 (102260165)|EXECUTION_FINISHED

Comment: The admin of the org should have received an email with more detailed information. Look for that email and you may be able to find the issue much quicker. All I can say from the above is that `Attitude to activity` is likely not or not set when it is being evaluated. One reason I refuse to use process builder when dependability is required. It does not handle gracefully nulls etc. and has issues with cross object fields. It can bring down critical business processes. Usually just switch back to workflows.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to check out this article.  https://salesforceyoda.com/2014/05/06/how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-test-my-flow/

specifically you are not handling the faults for a given flow element.

"Any Record or Fast Element can have a Fault element attached to it, and your best practice is to ensure that every Record or Fast Element has a Fault element attached to it. A Fault element can be made by creating any element and drawing an arrow to it from your Record or Fast Element AFTER they already have an arrow pointing to another element. If the Flow errors on that source element, it will then perform whatever is in your Fault, rather than showing that “unhandled fault”. That’s what unhandled means; it means that you haven’t defined what should happen when a fault happen"

Comment: Hey @benjaminPirih - thank you for the link and agree with the sentiment- it looks like the link you supplied is for "Visual Flow" and the OP was referencing Process Builder- related but PB is a simpler, more linear driven tool. Any context for debugging there?

Comment: check this out.. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_troubleshoot.htm&language=en_US&type=0  Also by the debug message it is pretty clear that the error is originating from a flow which might have been launched by an underlying process builder..

Error executing flow: Attitude_to_activity, FlowDefId: 3006F000000HGQX, FlowVersionId: 3016F0000000YRY 23:18:39.26 (100734715)|WF_FLOW_ACTION_ERROR_DETAIL|An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow
An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the flow.